# SwiftUI Navigation Bar Item with different destinations

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigation, swiftui-navigationview

I have a Navigation View with an Add button(NavigationBarItem) and want to set a different destination of the Navigation Bar item in each tab.

```
enum Tab: String {
    case income = "Income"
    case expenses = "Expenses"
    case budgets = "Budget"
    case investment = "Investment"
    case assets = "Asset"  
}
```

I have already tried to give the struct the view as raw value but this is not possible. How can I do this?

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            Text("Place Holder Income")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Income", systemImage: "star")
                }
                .tag(Tab.income)
                .navigationBarHidden(false)
            
            ExpensesView()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Expenses", systemImage: "star")
                }
                .tag(Tab.expenses)
                .navigationBarHidden(false)
            
            Text("Place Holder Budgets")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Budgets", systemImage: "star")
                }
                .tag(Tab.budgets)
                .navigationBarHidden(false)
            
            Text("Place Holder Investment")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Investment", systemImage: "star")
                }
                .tag(Tab.investment)
                .navigationBarHidden(false)
            
            Text("Place Holder Assets")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("Assets", systemImage: "star")
                }
                .tag(Tab.assets)
                .navigationBarHidden(false)
    }
        .navigationTitle(selection.rawValue)
        .navigationBarItems(
            trailing:
                NavigationLink("Add", destination: AddExpensesView())
        )
    
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you could have the add button open an "AddView" and pass the selected tab binding to that view. That view would act as a router view and present the appropriate add view (eg `AddExpensesview`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a function (in your view) that routes to the right destination (depending on the value of the "selection" property).

```
@ViewBuilder func addView() -> some View {
        switch selection {
        case .income: Text("Income destination")
        case .expenses: Text("Expenses destination")
        default: Rectangle()
        }
    }
```

Your `NavigationLink` calls this view builder  :

```
NavigationLink("Add", destination: addView())
```